# Error encountered when deployinig a maven java project into WildFly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, websocket, jboss

I am trying to deploy a war file (Java JDK 1.8, Maven project) into WildFly and got the following error below:

===============================================================================================

```
11:59:27,872 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test-driver.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test-driver.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:254)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
        at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap$WebSocketListener.contextInitialized(Bootstrap.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
        ... 10 more

11:59:27,952 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test-driver.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test-driver.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer"}}
11:59:28,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "test-driver.war" (runtime-name : "test-driver.war")
11:59:28,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test-driver.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
WFLYCTL0448: 1 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

===============================================================================================

I have tried the following exclusion in my java project pom after some research:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And also the following in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
  <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
   <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        <subsystem name="jsf" />
        <subsystem name="weld" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
   </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Seems like you're using a Tomcat specific class in your code which won't be compatible with Wildfly classes. Why does your build depend on Tomcat in the first place?

Comment: You don't need `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` if you are deploying in WildFly or any JEE Container.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-app-to-jboss-wildfly might help

Comment: @Thomas The development was done locally and tested locally on a tomcat server, therefore there were such dependencies.

Comment: Well, if you plan to deploy your application in different environments then your development should reflect that, i.e. you should treat your local environment the same as your test or production environment. That means that your application's dependencies should _not_ reflect that.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam did follow this example and fixed the scope to provided instead of compile, the same error still exist.

Comment: @Thomas good point